# Update c:foreach / ui:repeat with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

Trying to update c:foreach with javascript . even though the view is refreshing the new value which is inserted into DB is not been shown in the view . I had also tried with ui:repeat and a:repeat situation is same . Any changes which i need to do .

```
<div id="spModOutput">
    <ui:repeat value="#{ActionClass.listMethod()}" var="scenarioVar">
        "#{scenarioVar.scenarioId}"
    </ui:repeat>
</div>

<script>
    $('#newSpScenarioId').on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('scenarioFormForAction:createNewScenarioSp').click();
    });
</script>

<script>
    function afterCompleteLoadTree() {
        alert("ROW CREATED IN DB  !!!");
        $('#spModOutput').fadeOut(100);
        $('#spModOutput').fadeIn(100);
        $('#spModOutput').jqxTree("refresh");
    }
</script>

<h:form id="scenarioFormForAction">
    <a4j:commandLink id="createNewScenarioSp" style="visibility: hidden;" 
        action="#{ActionClass.createNewRow()}" 
        oncomplete="afterCompleteLoadTree()">
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Where do you think you refresh the 'repeat'  with new data from the server?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this work, since richfaces is obsolete I can't recall the exact solution.

```
<script>
$('#newSpScenarioId').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('scenarioFormForAction:createNewScenarioSp').click();
});
</script>

<script>
    function afterCompleteLoadTree() {
        alert("ROW CREATED IN DB  !!!");
        $('#spModOutput').fadeOut(100);
        $('#spModOutput').fadeIn(100);
        $('#spModOutput').jqxTree("refresh");
    }
</script>

<h:form id="scenarioFormForAction">
    //put tree in a form
    <a4j:outputPanel id="msg"> //use outputPanel
    <div id="spModOutput">
        <ui:repeat value="#{ActionClass.listMethod()}" var="scenarioVar">
            "#{scenarioVar.scenarioId}"
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
    <a4j:commandLink id="createNewScenarioSp" style="visibility: hidden;" 
        action="#{ActionClass.createNewRow()}" 
        oncomplete="afterCompleteLoadTree()"
        reRender="msg"> //use reRender attr
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Please add some context to the answer (what you changed/added and why)

Comment: (I know there is some comment in the code but the 'why' is more relevant here for OP... Cheers (upvoted)

Comment: let me check your solution Omid . i will let you know shortly !!

Comment: No @Omid it is not working and reRender is not available in richfaces in its newer version

Comment: used p:commandLink update="@all" and c:forEach which is working fine now !!